# SSMS Export Wizard "Enable Identity Insert" Not Working

Tags: sql-server, ssms, plesk

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to export data from a local database to a remote database.  The Export Wizard is ignoring the "Enable Identity Insert" setting, so the Ids in the destination table end up different from the source table.

I've confirmed that I can use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableName ON;` in the destination database to manually enter Ids for data, so that part is working.

I've seen other questions posted about this issue, but they are many years old and do not have an answer. (Example: [Enable identity insert is not working when importing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630316/enable-identity-insert-is-not-working-when-importing-data))

Why does the Export Wizard ignore "Enable Identity Insert"?

More context:

- Using .Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer
- Destination database is hosted in Plesk

Comment: Actually I don't have any answer for your question, but are you used 'Generate Scripts' instead of 'Export Wizard' ?

Comment: "Generate Scripts" generates T-SQL, which is useful for table structures, stored procs, etc, but not useful for data transfer.

Comment: Nope, You can use "Generate Scripts" also for data transfer, it is not configured by default, so you should change some settings to enable this via  `Generate Scripts` >> `Advanced` button that located into third tab (Set Scripting Options) >> change `Types of data to script` to be `Schema and data`. Enjoy!

Comment: [screenshot for clarification](https://suar.me/eXB23)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that about Generate Scripts! I've confirmed this method works.  Unfortunately it is impractical for the table sizes I'm dealing with: 2-10GB each.

Comment: Update: Export Wizard also ignores "Enable Identity Insert" from one local db to another local db (for me).  Maybe there is something wrong with my SSMS installation.

Comment: Having the same issue.  I'm exporting from a local database to an Azure SQL Server database (and same problem if I try going the other direction, importing to Azure from the local database).  Seems like this worked in the past.